# Query a Neo4j graph includes all labels of nodes and type of relationship distinctly

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm new at Neo4j and I'm wondering is there any way to query a graph with vertices are labels of all nodes and edges are type of all relationship in the database? Thanks for your time!

Comment: you want to get schema of neo4j db?

Comment: Yeah exactly, do you know which cypher command could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for upper versions from neo4j 3.0 you can use below query

```
// What is related, and how
CALL db.schema()
```

[image]

you can simply find this query in your neo4j browser console

[image]

Comment: Wow, this helps me so much! Thank for your answer

Comment: @CyrusCobrazure If answer has helped you to solve your problem then you can accept it